# Conditional Formatting Excel with formula for 2 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to set a conditional format such that

Cell B minus Cell A , if number is more than 15, cell B should turn red in colour. 
This should be for ALL cells in column B. How do I have it such that the difference between the 2 cells affect the conditional formatting, and this is translated down the rest of the cells in that column?

Then, I want it to be the same when Cell C minus Cell B, if number is more than 15, Cell C should turn red in colour. 
When Cell D minus Cell C, if number is more than 15, Cell D turns red in colour... etc.

Also, what should be the cells that are selected for the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Columns B to what ever Column is your last.
Go to Conditional-Formatting -> New Rule, then click on the last option (new rule with formula or what ever it's called in english). then use this Formula:

```
=IF(B1<>"",(B1-A1)>15,0)
```

Then click on the format button and from the fill tab select the red color.

Comment: Doesn't work, am I typing something wrong? Tried a few combinations...

https://www.screencast.com/t/U9VhMEzi3LVB

https://www.screencast.com/t/cVKL9NRxuYH

Comment: @Min L What language is your Excel in?

Comment: English! 

By the way, I added screenshots in the previous comment so you can see what I'm typing in...

Comment: `=AND(B1<>"",B1-A1>15)`

Comment: Don't use the $ to lock the Cells.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost and do not wrap the formula in `""` it is a formula not a string.

Comment: @MinL And you have to select the whole columns by clicking on the "B" at the top part of the range and then drag across till the last column

Comment: @MarcoGetrost I removed the $ and dragged across, but this is what shows. https://www.screencast.com/t/hzqIUJybL

Comment: @ScottCraner Tried your formula, some cells lighted up but they aren't the right cells. Should be those that are 15 and above when they minus the cell on the left: https://www.screencast.com/t/tOkB7nkz4T

Comment: @MinL Ok. for your example, press on "I" and drag till "J", then click on the conditional formatting. Then type in this formula: =IF(I1<>"",I1-H1>=15,0) (Just coppy and paste the formula)

Comment: @MarcoGetrost ok now there are other cells that light up but they aren't according to the formula. Only those that have a different of 15 should light up right? https://www.screencast.com/t/w6OJwSe6pbnT

Comment: @MinL Do you have other Conditional Formatting Rules saved? Go to Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules and delte all the other ones.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost Ok cool I started a brand new sheet and now it turns red correctly. Just that the one that should be turning red should be the cell that is minusing the number. Meaning, B1-A1 more than 15 then B1 should light up, not A1. https://www.screencast.com/t/EXWUpldHdO9p

Comment: @MinL You probably highlighted Columns A and B and then entered the Conditional Format-Formula. You need to highlight Columns B and C and then entere the formula. So delete the rule you just added, and do the same again, only this time for columns B and C

Comment: @MarcoGetrost It works now. Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @MinL glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Under the Conditional Formatting button, I was able to create a new rule with the formula =B2>A2+15, then added the appropriate formatting.  I then used Format Painter to drag it to the necessary cells.